# Applying a function n times

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I am trying to apply a function to a value `n` times.

Currently, I have

```
let rec n_times (f, n, v) = 
 if n > 0 then
  n_times f n-1 (f v)
 else 
  v
```

For some reason I keep getting an error that says

```
This expression has type 'a but an expression was expected of type 'a * int * 'b 
The type variable 'a occurs inside 'a * int * 'b
```

I saw a few posts that address the same problem I am working on but none of them gets the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first line of your code: you say "I declare a function called `n_times` that take a triplet `(f, n, v)` so one argument" then at the call site (third line) you give 3 arguments.

To fix this: write `let rec n_times f n v =` on line 1 or `n_times (f, n-1, (f v))` on line 3.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the function to take a 3-tuple of values. So when you call it recursively you need to supply a 3-tuple:

```
n_times (f, n - 1, f v)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two problems, it would help to know what the purpose is other than recursion.

To get this to run you have to change your third line. `n_times` is defined with three inputs so it needs to be called with three. Also the function is defined to take a general, integer, and general input and output a general type.

You could remove `(f v)` and input just `v` every loop,

```
# let rec n_times (f, n, v) =
    if n > 0 then
        n_times (f , n-1 , v)
    else
      v;;
val n_times : 'a * int * 'b -> 'b = <fun>
# n_times(2,3,4);;
- : int = 4
```

This will however always return just v at the end.

You could also replace `(f v)` with a list and preapped it each loop,

```
# let rec n_times (f, n, v) =
    if n > 0 then
        n_times (f , n-1 , f::v)
    else
      v;;
val n_times : 'a * int * 'a list -> 'a list = <fun>
# n_times(2,3,[4]);;
- : int list = [2; 2; 2; 4]
# n_times(2,5,[4]);;
- : int list = [2; 2; 2; 2; 2; 4]
```

This allows the list to grow with each loop.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a misunderstanding in how OCaml functions with multiple arguments are defined. You should replace

```
let rec n_times (f, n, v) =
```

with:

```
let rec n_times f n v =
```